# Open interval written as a union of half-open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Perhaps a more basic question but I am really trying to understand this why can an open set $$(a,b)$$ be written as such:

$$(a,b) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+1/n,b)$$

Should it not be the intersection? Wouldn't that make more sense? I know that $$(a,b) = \cup[a+1/n, b-1/n]$$ I understand the end of the interval and that union would eventually get close to $b$ but not touch it. But the part with $a$ I am having trouble seeing, it seems like it would be larger than $(a,b)$ since you include it in the interval $(a+1,b)$.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the specifics.

Comment: $(a,b)$ where $a\gt b$ is empty so you shouldn't have any problem including those intervals in the union.

Comment: Oh I totally thought about this the wrong way!! I don't know why I was visualizing a-1/n... thanks thought! Sometimes you get lost in the math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be the intersection.  As $\ n\ $ increases from $\ 1\ $ to $\ \infty\ $, $\ a+\frac{1}{n}\ $ *decreases* from $\ a+1\ $ towards $\ a\ $, to which it gets arbitrarily close as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $. Thus, the intervals $\ \left[a+\frac{1}{n},b\right)\ $ get bigger and bigger as $\ n\ $ increases, and they are all subsets of $\ (a,b)\ $:
$$
\Big[a+1,b\Big)\subset\left[a+\frac{1}{2},b\right)\subset\dots\subset \left[a+\frac{1}{n},b\right)\subset\dots\subset\Big(a,b\Big)\ .
$$
Moreover, if $\ x\ $ is any member of $\ (a,b)\ $, then there is a positive integer $\ n\ $ such that $\ x\in\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b\right)\ $ (in fact, $\ n=\left\lceil\frac{1}{x-a}\right\rceil\ $ will do), so every such $\ x\ $ must lie in $\ \bigcup_\limits{n=1}^\infty\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b\right) \ $.  It follows that
$$
\Big(a,b\Big)\subseteq \bigcup_\limits{n=1}^\infty\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b\right)\subseteq\Big(a,b\Big)\ .
$$
On the other hand $\ \bigcap _\limits{n=1}^\infty\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b\right)=\big[a+1,b\big)\ $, because $\ \big[a+1,b\big)\subseteq\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b\right)\ $ for all positive integers $\ n\ $.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a real brain fart there!